# Calculating distance between target node and group of "high-risk" nodes

Tags: graph-theory, network-analysis

Given a network with weighted edges, each describes the rate of contact between a pair of individuals (modes) such that e.g., a weight of 0.2 corresponds to 0.2 contact per unit time, is there a way to quantify the distance separating a target node and a group of nodes with particular characteristics (e.g., carrying high risk for disease transmission)?

In the figure below, high-risk nodes inhabit the red region where the background force of infection `\lambda(x)` scales with local density, i.e., amount of nearby neighbors in *only* the red region `n(x)`. Nodes in the white region are partially "protected" and suffer negligible background force of infection - their risks stem solely from direct and indirect contacts with individuals in the red region. Here, we simplistically assume that, for the two nodes on the left, `\lambda(x)=0.8` and, for the top node, `\lambda(x)=0.4`. Edge weights are either 0.1 or 0.2, as indicated by line widths. The aim is to, in some ways, measure the risk experienced by node *i* under a specified network structure. Is it as simple as computing the summed geodesic distance from node *i* to all nodes in red, i.e., 0.6+0.5+0.8=1.9, or are there more sophisticated methods that also account for values of `\lambda(x)` and other network factors?

[image]

Comment: It depends on what the edge weights mean.  Are they related to the risk of transmission, or something else.   You need to provide a lot more details about your model construction.

Comment: @ravenspoint Great feedback. I've revised my description of the problem. Hopefully it has been the question clearer.

Comment: " measure the risk experienced by node"  What are the units of this measure?  Probability of being infected over a given period?  or something else? "0.6+0.5+0.8=1.9"  If this was correct, what would the 1.9 mean?  What does "force of infection" mean?